# I need a java.time parser that can handle any valid W3C ISO 8601 date/time string

Tags: java, time, iso8601

There doesn't seem to be a built-in java.time parser that can handle any valid [W3C ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.html) date/time string.

It should return a ZonedDateTime, with missing fields set to 0 as specified in the W3C spec.

This seems to be such a common use case, im surprised its not part of the standard library, and i imagine its been solved multiple times outside the library. Anyone have solutions?

Comment: Why not using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`?

Comment: "*i imagine its been solved multiple times outside the library*" Maybe it has, but asking for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not even really sure what you're asking. You want a parser than can read a year, or a year-and-month, or a year-and-month-and-day, etc? And you want to set missing fields to zero? So "2021" should be parsed as 00:00:00 Zeroth of Zerouary 2021? ZonedDateTime cannot represent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-)

The examples in your link, [W3C ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.html) are `OffsetDateTime` and not `ZonedDateTime`. A `ZonedDateTime` require a timezone ID e.g. `Europe/London`. Also, JDBC 4.2 supports `OffsetDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime`.

You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting` to parse your string into an `OffsetDateTime` with default values.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(zoneId);
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]['T'HH[:mm[:ss[.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSSSS][.SSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]]]][XXX]")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, now.getMonthValue())
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, now.getDayOfMonth())
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)     
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        //Test          
        Stream.of(
                    "1997",
                    "1997-07",
                    "1997-07-16",
                    "1997-07-16T19:20+01:00",
                    "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00",
                    "1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1997-05-21T00:00Z
1997-07-21T00:00Z
1997-07-16T00:00Z
1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
1997-07-16T19:20:30.450+01:00
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I agree, OffsetDateTime is a better fit than ZonedDateTime. Your solution looks good and I am accepting it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> W3C ISO 8601

[That document](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.html) is a self-declared “profile” of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, not the standard itself.

> This seems to be such a common use case, im surprised its not part of the standard library

The *java.time* classes do indeed use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing text.

There is no universal parser because context matters. A year, a year-month, a date, a time-of-day, a date with time-of-day, a date with time-of-day with offset, a date with time-of-day with time zone, are all different animals. You would not ordinarily expect values of different types to arrive arbitrarily.

If you really do have such a collection of arbitrary types, then simply perform a series of parse attempts. Trap for the `DateTimeParseException` exception. If parsing with one *java.time* class fails, move on to the next *java.time* class.

You said:

> It should return a ZonedDateTime, with missing fields set to 0 as specified in the W3C spec.

How would you turn a year-only value into a `ZonedDateTime` object? What should be the month and day values? Zero is not acceptable there. What time zone? You’ll need to specify your desired zone. What time-of-day? Zeros for time does not work as not all days in some zones start the day at 00:00:00.

For these reasons, a universal parser is not possible. You need to perform the parsing according to the business rules of your particular app for your particular input data.

You can come closer to your desired universal parser by establishing default values with the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class. See [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641742/642706).

Comment: This insight gives the right guidance to the readers. Hesitantly I started writing an answer using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) but then I saw this great answer and discarded my answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I think an Answer with an example using `parseDefaulting` would be useful here. I added a mention of your comment to the Answer in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, Basil Bourque. I've posted an answer.